# scrapy: spider destructor (__del__) never executed

Tags: python, destructor, scrapy

I have created an scrapy spider that works well (it does what is supposed to do), but when finish working it doesn't execute the destructor code (**del**)

Versions are:
 - python 2.7.3
 - scrapy 0.24.6
 - Fedora 18

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
stuff
def __del__(self):
    stuff_1
```

How could I execute my "stuff-1" code when MySpider is done?

Answer (score 0):

Use signals. In particular, [`spider_closed`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed) signal:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        stuff_1()
```

Answer (score 0):

@alecxe's answer is now [deprecated](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1762)

Use the [`from_crawler` class method](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed) instead:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider closed')
```